# How to Load other extension's new tab page as iFrame in my extension's new tab page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension, cors

> content scripts can't be injected into extension pages with
>   chrome-extension:// scheme.

just load the page in a iFrame, I don't want/need to load in it a content script, so the user can have the best of both worlds or have their cake and eat it too, my tabs manager extension and their favorite *[default new tab extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/momentum/laookkfknpbbblfpciffpaejjkokdgca)* from the chrome store.

### my experiment

I opened dev tools from the options page of a other extension,

```
chrome-extension://ckkdlimhmcjmikdlpkmbgfkaikojcbjk/content/options.html
```

appended this HTML snippet, adds a iframe to dom

```
<iframe src="chrome-extension://hddnkoipeenegfoeaoibdmnablmgkpip/newtab.html">
</iframe>
```

the iFrame loads but it's blank white page with invisible html elements (assets wasn't loaded, styles not applied and JS not executed)

**error messages in console**

```
Denying load of chrome-extension://hddnkoipeenegfoeaoibdmnablmgkpip/newtab.html. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-AmiIBiDMlUtAs2tJB7jErMe/d3rBPYNUQQIZZdI0/mw='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

multiple ~identical to the second error message followed it

there has to be a **secure*** way to display a page from one extension in a page in other extension, this is a appropriate, valid use, 
whilst you can reject toolbar extensions (remember pre-chrome Internet Explorer toolbars?).

* "secure" meaning that one relative frame/window can't access the DOM of another relative frame of a extension page or manipulate it (execute JS in it).
(relative = child/parent/sibling)
Chrome already does that with the native default pdf plugin iframe.

Comment: Imagine someone writes a email-extension for chrome that lists emails of the user in an extra popover. Should you be able to open the window of this extension in your own extension and read wrong it?

I guess there is a reason why this will never work.

Comment: @DB I mentioned secure, perhaps I should make it bold. that means one relative frame/window can't access the dom of a other relative frame of a extension page or manipulate it (execute JS in it). (relative = child/parent/sibling) chrome already does that with the native default pdf plugin iframe. I agree with you.

Comment: I see `ckkdlimhmcjmikdlpkmbgfkaikojcbjk` is a [markdown viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdown-viewer/ckkdlimhmcjmikdlpkmbgfkaikojcbjk).  What is `hddnkoipeenegfoeaoibdmnablmgkpip`?  I get a 404 in the Chrome Web Store.

Comment: Oh - I see - is `hdd...` an unpacked version of [Momentum](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/momentum/laookkfknpbbblfpciffpaejjkokdgca) (`lao...`)?

Answer (score 1):

I had just the same question! :)  I got this to work only for extensions that are set up for it.  I tested with two unpacked extensions, so neither is in the store.  From extension ID `omf...`, I wanted to load a page form extension ID `oii...`.

#### Solution

- In `omf`, I put a `<div id="container"/>` and a `<script src="popup.js"/>` in my `popup.html`.
- In `omf`, in `popup.js`, I did:

  ```
  let pc = document.getElementById('container');
  let iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.src = "chrome-extension://oiifekahljigbmnkdacklolgniafenlj/quux.html";
  pc.appendChild(iframe);
  ```

  and it worked fine.
  **Note** I did this **after** `onload` of `popup.html` - I didn't try it before `onload`.

#### Caveat

It only worked when the target extension, `oii`, declared `quux.html` in its [`web_accessible_resources` manifest entry](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).  Specifically, `oii` has the following partial manifest:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  ...
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "quux.html"
  ]
}
```

If I removed `quux.html` from the `web_accessible_resources` section in `oii`, then the `<iframe>` in `omf` gave me the "Refused to execute" messages you saw.

#### A debugging aid

Interestingly, in my case, the "Refused to execute" error messages were actually for scripts in the built-in Chrome error page `chrome-extension://invalid/`.  I was able to get that page to load by manually copying the `hash` values from the error messages into the `content_security_policy` manifest entry in `omf`.  For example, in `omf`'s `manifest.json`:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'sha256-AmiIBiDMlUtAs2tJB7jErMe/d3rBPYNUQQIZZdI0/mw=' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource: ; object-src 'self'"
```

with as many space-separated `sha256` entries as there were error messages.  Each error message relates to a particular script with its own hash, and the messages thoughtfully tell you the hashes!  So, if you had four errors, you would wind up with:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'sha256-1' 'sha256-2' 'sha256-3' 'sha256-4'"
```

with `sha256-`1..4 replaced by the actual hashes from the four error messages.  If you are having script problems, and you are confident the scripts are safe, you can add their hashes and retry.  Note that you have to reload the whole extension when you change the `content_security_policy`.

(In the example above, the `object-source 'self'` is part of the [default policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#restrictions), so I left it in during my testing.  The `blob`, `filesystem`, and `chrome-extension-resource` came from [this section of the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-remote-script).)

#### Security

You asked about security.  Per woxxom [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=769823#c3), permissions follow the page origin.  That was the case in my testing, so I think you're fine.

- `omf` has the `tabs` permission, and `oii` does not.  If I run

  ```
  chrome.windows.getAll({populate:true},function(wins){console.log(wins);})
  ```

  in `omf`'s context, I get the `url` for each open tab.  If I run it in `oii`'s context, I do not get the `url` or any other information that requires the `tabs` permission.
- Similarly, in `omf`, `window.frames[`*oii's iframe index*`]` is `undefined`, and in the `oii` iframe, `window.parent` is undefined.
- However, if I load an `omf` iframe from `omf`'s popup, the iframe and parent can communicate with each other via `window.frames` and `window.parent`, and the iframe has access to the `tabs` permission.